# How to write a Powershell script to update a DNS server using BIND tools and nsupdate?

Tags: powershell, dns, bind

I recently started coding a DNS updater which takes the parameters of `{operation} {domain} {TTL} {Type} {target}`. And before I continue with it, I wanted to write a Powershell script to test if with it I can take these parameters and for DNS to either modify, delete or add a record.

The steps should go as follows:

1. `C:/Users/User> nsupdate`
2. `> server 10.10.10.10`
3. `> update add mydomain.example.com 86400 A 10.1.1.1`
4. `> send`

I couldn't manage to find much on this topic, mostly just for bash. If you got any pointers and guidance information please point me in the right direction :)

PS: I got Bind-toolsonly installed on my Windows 10 machine

Comment: You may not need to use `nsupdate` at all if you have access to some DNS library that allows you to create any kind of DNS packet/record and you would craft the update yourself then.

Answer (score -1):

You can put all your 3 commands in a file and direct `nsupdate` to read it as `nsupdate commands.txt` or just send them over STDIN.

I do not know the syntax of Powershell but under an Unix shell it will be something like that which you could probably easily translate:

```
 echo -e "server 10.10.10.10\nupdate add mydomain.example.com 86400 A 10.1.1.1\nsend" | nsupdate
```